# How to send a SMS in android?

Tags: android, sms

I want to send a SMS to user as notification. How can we send SMS to a particular mobile number.
Please also tell which service will be used for sending SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, you can use `SmsManager API` or device’s `Built-in SMS` application to send a SMS message.

**For example:**

***SmsManager API***

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

***Built-in SMS application***

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content");
  sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
  startActivity(sendIntent);
```

both need `SEND_SMS` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```